# Size of positional encoding in a tensorflow tutorial

Tags: tensorflow, transformer-model

I am trying to understand and play with this tensorflow tutorial about the transformer architecture and I find something I don't understand in the Class Decoder. Why is the self.pos_encoding = positional_encoding(target_vocab_size, self.d_model) called with targe_vocab_size instead of the maximum length of sequences? See this link and code for the class below. Any idea? https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r2/tutorials/text/transformer.ipynb

```
class Decoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff, target_vocab_size, 
               rate=0.1):
    super(Decoder, self).__init__()

    self.d_model = d_model
    self.num_layers = num_layers

    self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(target_vocab_size, d_model)
    self.pos_encoding = positional_encoding(target_vocab_size, self.d_model)

    self.dec_layers = [DecoderLayer(d_model, num_heads, dff, rate) 
                       for _ in range(num_layers)]
    self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate)
    def call(self, x, enc_output, training, 
           look_ahead_mask, padding_mask):

    seq_len = tf.shape(x)[1]
    attention_weights = {}

    x = self.embedding(x)  # (batch_size, target_seq_len, d_model)
    x *= tf.math.sqrt(tf.cast(self.d_model, tf.float32))
    x += self.pos_encoding[:, :seq_len, :]

    x = self.dropout(x, training=training)

    for i in range(self.num_layers):
      x, block1, block2 = self.dec_layers[i](x, enc_output, training,
                                             look_ahead_mask, padding_mask)

      attention_weights['decoder_layer{}_block1'.format(i+1)] = block1
      attention_weights['decoder_layer{}_block2'.format(i+1)] = block2

    # x.shape == (batch_size, target_seq_len, d_model)
    return x, attention_weights
```

Comment: Would this code break if we processed sentences longer than the vocabulary size?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I convinced myself that the tutorial has a bug. When constructing the positional embeddings `self.pos_encoding = positional_encoding(target_vocab_size, self.d_model)` you should use MAX_LENGTH instead of target_vocab_size. This fixes a number of issues I was having when using a smaller vocabulary and longer sentences. The example in the tutorial does not break since in their example `target_vocab_size > MAX_LENGTH` so no issues with their setting.